# Problem while response from firebase realtime databse in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I want to fetch data from the realtime database ,and the data is in the form of 
MAP < String , MAP < String , String > >
Here is the problem

```
 const  url='https://XYZfirebaseio.com/products.json';
  try{
   final resp= await http.get(url);
   print(json.decode(resp.body));
   final extractedData=json.decode(resp.body) as Map<String,dynamic>;

   final List<Product>loadedProducts=[];
   extractedData.forEach((id,data){
     loadedProducts.add(
       Product(
         id: data,
         title: data['title'],
         description: data['descripiton'],
         price:data['price'],
         imageUrl: data['imageUrl'],
         isFavorite: data['imageUrl']
       )
     );
   });
```

while the Product class is just a normal class and has PRICE attribute as Double,every else property is String.When this code is executed it creates the following error.

> I/flutter ( 4228): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'String'

What data structure/method/workaround can i use?

the Product class

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
class Product with ChangeNotifier{
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product(
    {
      @required this.id,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.description,
      @required this.price,
       this.isFavorite = false,
     @required this.imageUrl
    }
  );
```

Comment: How it is possible that the data you want to retrieve is in form of ```Map<String, Map<String, String>>```?, Firebase database always return data as ```Map<String, dynamic>```, can you share your Product class?

Comment: Yes u are absolutely right ..but i did mean THE EXACT data m getting..i simply described it more.But the problem is same...it returns the type u mentioned... but..dart doesn't recognise it.

Comment: Add your product class to your question so I will be able to inspect everything

Comment: You can see Line 5 of the code....this line causes the mentioned error.

Comment: In that case, flutter is complaining about receiving a simple String when you expect a ```Map<String, dynamic>```

Comment: My apologies, I didn't understand.The Product class is now in the question though.

Comment: The error states that the variable "extractedData" is receiving a String when you expect something else, check the resp.body and if you can post it here also to debug a little what you are getting

Comment: _print(json.decode(resp.body)) yeilds_   

  `I/flutter ( 4307): {-LvsecaYtE8jB81j6USh: {description: DummyTitle, imageUrl: https.dummmyd.jpg, isFavourite: false, title: DummyTitle}}
`

Comment: Update:
I ran the debugger and i came to know that the  **forEach** method causes the error, as soon as the control reaches forEach , it is sent to Catch block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed in your forEach loop, forEach take a function with two parameters, one with key (you called it "id"), and another one with value (you called it "data"), and the problem is your id parameter over the Product class as it is a String, but you are assining to it a Map value.

If you check your json result you got `I/flutter ( 4307): {-LvsecaYtE8jB81j6USh: {description: DummyTitle, imageUrl: https.dummmyd.jpg, isFavourite: false, title: DummyTitle}}`, so the forEach loop will only iterate just one time, the key will be `-LvsecaYtE8jB81j6USh` (your "id"), and the value will be `{description: DummyTitle, imageUrl: https.dummmyd.jpg, isFavourite: false, title: DummyTitle}` (your "data"), so as you can see, you are assigning it wrong.

The correct way to do it will be:

```
extractedData.forEach((id,data) {
     loadedProducts.add(
       Product(
         id: id,
         title: data['title'],
         description: data['descripiton'],
         price:data['price'],
         imageUrl: data['imageUrl'],
         isFavorite: data['imageUrl']
       )
     );
   });
```

This is, suppossing that the value "-LvsecaYtE8jB81j6USh" is the real id you want.